# Better jQuery statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the (comma delimited) string of values inside of `hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers`,  take each value, and do something with it.  This works, but it feels a bit dirty.

```
    $($(".hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers").val().split(",")).each(function(index, val) {
        $(".phoneCB[data-rowNumber='" + val + "']").children().attr("checked", "checked");
    });
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly optimized (but could be optimized further, specifically by using a for loop instead of `jQuery.each()`):

```
var numbers = $(".hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers").val().split(","),
    $phoneCb = $(".phoneCB");

$(numbers).each(function(index, val) {
    $phoneCb.filter("[data-rowNumber='" + val + "']").children().attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way....

```
var checkedNumbers  = $(".hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers").val().split(",");

var processCheckedNumbers = function(index, val) {
        $(".phoneCB[data-rowNumber='" + val + "']").children().attr("checked", "checked");
 }

$(checkedNumbers).each(processCheckedNumbers);
```

Comment: Yeah - probably as good as I'll get, but shouldn't val be hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers[val] in the body of your loop?

Comment: You should add `if(hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers.hasOwnProperty(val))`, and `$("input.phoneCB[data-rowNumber='" + val + "']")` should be `$("input.phoneCB[data-rowNumber='" + hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers[val] + "']")`

Comment: @Rocket - what's the purpose of `if(hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers.hasOwnProperty(val))`?  Isn't that guaranteed to always be true since each val will always be an index of the array?

Comment: @Adam: If you add methods to the array prototype (`Array.prototype.unique = function(){...}`), they will appear as a `val` in `for(var val in hdnCheckedPhoneNumbers)`.

Comment: @Rocket - great point, thank you.  Migeul's improved answer makes it a moot point, but that's good advice to remember.